# How to add text before or after a single element through css

Tags: html, css

I don't have access to modify the source html and the classes cover such a large span of things, I'm having trouble adding to it as I want.

I'm trying to add text to the area that already has text.

Tried the following but it does nothing.

`.content div:firstchild:after { content: 'Test'; }`

When I do the following, it adds the text but it adds it numerous times because there are numerous divs and other elements (I've tried to add it directly into the table, after b, etc)

`.content div:after { content: 'Test'; }`

[what I see when trying the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qeAB.png)

[the html of that section of the page from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYQS9.png)

Comment: Use `::before` or `::after`.

Comment: It’s `:first-child` and `::after`.

Comment: thank you!! is there a different code to use when inserting before a table? I can do `.content table:before { content: 'Test'; }` and it works but it populates more than once because. there's more than one table. `.contentModuleContent table:first-child::before { content: 'Test'; }` does nothing again

Comment: _"does nothing again"_ - of course it doesn't, because that table clearly isn't the first child of its parent. But `:first-of-type` should work here.

Comment: ah! thanks so much! clearly, I'm new to this, so still how it all works together

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector has a typo in it, `:firstchild` should be `:first-child`.

This should do what you need it to do:

```
.content div:first-child:after { content: 'Test'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `:before` and `:after` selectors you specify which content should be inserted before (or after) the content inside of that element. Input elements have no content.

```
        .content div:first-child:before
        {
            color: green;
            content: 'working ';
        }
        .content div:not(:first-child):after
        {
            color: green;
            content: ' is working';
        }


        .content div:before:first-child
        {
            color: red;
            content: 'this will never show up';
        }
        .content div:after:not(:first-child)
        {
            color: red;
            content: 'and this will not show up either';
        }
```